# Comparison of areas under curves

Tags: time-series, hypothesis-testing

I have two broken line graphs representing the evolution of some proportion over time in men and in women. I would like to compare these two curves. My idea was to compute the areas under them. I did it using the trapezoidal rule. Now, my question is how to compare these two AUC's? I'd like to test the null hypothesis that AUC1 = AUC2. Any idea?

Comment: are these points evenly spaced?  could you approximate by just taking the sum of each time point?

Comment: What is the statistical or probabilistic meaning of the area under the curve? The average proportion over the period? Isn't that a very reductive representation of the data?

Comment: There is insufficient information here. If you want to do hypothesis testing, you need to assume some kind of model. But that is difficult to do without knowing what you actually mean. Are these the *same* men and women at different points in time? Or different ones? Are they a sample from the population of interest, or the entire one? What about the problem makes the area under the curve more interesting than other properties of the curves one might compare? And so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While my comment that ideally more information should be given holds, if this really is all you have to go on you could at least say *something* by performing a permutation test. In other words: calculate AUC1 - AUC2 for all random re-labelings of gender and see where the value you actually observed falls within that distribution.